# Update table of two different database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

This is the query to update table in one database that is of other

```
Update
  test.temp a,
  test2.temp b
Set a.name=b.name
Where a.no=b.no;
```

Now I don't want to write every field i.e `a.name=b.name`

Is there any solution?

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem, could you specify the problem in more details?

Comment: are you saying the tables have a different "format", e.g different fields or field-names?